# What are the different test scenarios to be checked for giving license to a client

Tags: manual-testing

i have a web app .License is given to the customer to use it.What could be the possible test scenarios that has to be checked before deploying it.I have found out a few 
1)Change the server time zone .
2)Make the server move across different time zones

Please help me with other scenarios

Comment: what kind of license you are distributing?whether license key was validated at server side/client side?

Comment: What effect does the licence have? If the user has no licence, should they be prevented from accessing the app at all? Or should they be given access to some functions but not others? Is the licence date-limited?

Comment: This might help: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/what-are-some-good-test-cases-in-order-to-do-license-key-authentication-while-so

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question this were my

**License Scenarios**

You haven't mentioned what type of license it is,Based on that the license Scenario's will vary

In general the license key might be of three types

- Text key
- Key file
- Hardware key

**Text key**

The trial period is often present in this scheme. We’ll consider the check-list with it as it’s more complicated – for the scheme without trial period some tests will be simply omitted.

It’s recommended to check:

- the limitations of the application functionality (if there is such during the trial period) and correspondingly the availability of the full functionality after the successful licensing.
- the possibility of licensing during the trial period
- application response to the input of the incorrect registration data (if the key consists of the several fields then you should make the separate test for the each of them):

а. Key is corrupted

b. Key is absent

c. Key is typed in the wrong case

d. Key contains the extra symbols at the end and/or at the beginning

- application response to the input of the correct registration data
- application response to the input of the registration data provided for the previous versions of the tested application
- unlicensed application behavior after it has been reinstalled during the trial period
- application behavior after the trial period is over
- unlicensed application behavior after it has been reinstalled after the trial period is over
- application response to the system time change forward/backward (the most important here is to keep the trial period correct). Take into account that the system time change should be performed in BIOS because the one performed in the operating system does not have much effect.
- the possibility to register application after the trial period is over.
- application behavior after the registration data has been deleted, for example from the registry (usually after registration the deletion of these data is disabled).
- licensed application behavior after it was reinstalled.

**Key file**

Here you should pay attention on the aspects:

- Using a file with the correct name but with incorrect content and vice versa.
- Starting application after the file was deleted.
- Saving the file while the application is being reinstalled.
- Application behavior after the file has been replaced:

a. correct -> incorrect,

b. correct -> correct,

c. incorrect -> correct,

d. incorrect -> incorrect.

**Hardware key**

We should check:

- Application functioning with no special software for hardware key installed.
- Application functioning without hardware key.
- Unplugging hardware key while the application is running (here we should take into account 2 situations: application has some process run and application is in the standby mode):

a. Permissible waiting time for the key plugging.

b. Correct application behavior after the unplugged key is returned.

с. Correct application behavior if the waiting time is over and the key was not plugged.

- Application functioning if there are some other devices akin to the hardware key plugged (for example, if the key is USB device then it’s good to check its functioning together with flash drive).

Comment: Most of these checks (while interesting for all web apps) have nothing to do with licensing.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere apologies sir,kindly review it, now i updated answer according to question